# How can I get the values from other ColdFusion files

Tags: mysql, coldfusion, dreamweaver, coldfusion-8

Please consider the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>PieChart</title>
</head>

<body>
<div align="center">
<cfchart
         format="png"
         scalefrom="0"
         scaleto="1200000"
         pieslicestyle="solid">
    <cfchartseries
                 type="pie"
                 serieslabel="Website Traffic 2006"
                 seriescolor="blue">
        <cfchartdata item="% OPEN" value="30">
        <cfchartdata item="%DROPPED" value="1">
        <cfchartdata item="% PROCESSED" value="20">
        <cfchartdata item="% BOUNCE" value="1">
        <cfchartdata item="% DELIVERED" value="17">
        <cfchartdata item="% DEFERRED" value="31">
    </cfchartseries>
</cfchart>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The above file name is `"PieChart.cfm"`

In the above code, I have hard coded the values (30,1,20,1,17,31). However, I have other coldfusion files with me for example (`Count_Open.cfm` which has SQL statement inside it and the file is returning the value of `% OPEN` , similar is the case with other files as well, namely,  `Count_Dropped.cfm`,`Count_Delivered.cfm` rtc )

How can I use the values returned by above files in my file `PieChart.cfm` so that if the data keeps on changing, I don't have to run the files again and again and hard code the values.

Please help and let me know if my questions is not clear.

Thanks

Comment: I would use a CFC, especially if you're only getting data and not displaying anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cfinclude tag might be the way to go.  I would include this one in the other ones.  Pay attention that you are not duplicating doctype, html, head, or body tags.

Comment: Dan is right. CFINCLUDE is the straight way to get the data. But, if possible why don't you try to put all the %open etc queries as a method output of a CFC. This way, your code is well maintained and less in lines.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But still if I want to get the data in the `"value"` field of the above code using `cfinclude`, I'm wondering how can I do it?

Comment: @Dan Baracuk Any comments you would like to provide regarding my questions mentioned above?